# About socket connection timeout in C++ (UNIX)

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I have been working to put a 15 seconds timeout to a socket to avoid it to be blocked. So i configured it as non-blocking, then used select function, and works fine... when the computer is connected to a network!

If computer is disconnected from the network (for example, if Wi-Fi signal is turned off, or if you emove the ethernet plug), when I call connect function it returns inmediatly the "Network is unreachable" error.

Since I have a loop to get it reconnected if something like this happens, it is trying to connect MANY times, so I'm getting log files of gigabytes.

So, what I want is to set some kind of timeout for that too. It's not a timeout actually, but I want it to wait 15 seconds until it tries to connect again to avoid this problem. I was wrong when I thought that the timeout i have set as explained in paragraph 1 would fix this too. How can I make this then?

Comment: How about just sleeping for 15 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the `errno` and `sleep` if it's `ENETUNREACH`.

Comment: Aw man... this answer makes me feel stupid :(. I guess it's true, thanks!

Comment: it's part of POSIX.1-2001 and probably older standards as well.

Comment: You may set the timeout parameter of select() to 15 seconds !?